# For-loop to call fields for IDW-Interpolation

Tags: pyqgis, inverse-distance-weighted, for-loop

probably a question easy to answer, but I do not figure it out at the moment.
I'm using station-data and do a IDW-interpolation to get average climate values in layer. 
The station's data is arranged in a point-layer with fields for monthly values in the attribute table. 
I want loop trough all columns of the attribute table and carry out the interpolation with those.

Following code I use:

```py
fn = "C:/Users/Alex/Desktop/Masterarbeit/GIS/humidity_station.gpkg"
grundlage = iface.addVectorLayer(fn, '','ogr')
for f in grundlage.fields():
    grundlage_2 = processing.run(
            'saga:inversedistanceweightedinterpolation',
            {
                    'DW_BANDWIDTH': 1,
                    'DW_IDW_OFFSET': False,
                    'DW_IDW_POWER': 2,
                    'DW_WEIGHTING': 1,
                    'FIELD': str(f),
                    'SEARCH_DIRECTION': 0,
                    'SEARCH_POINTS_ALL': 0,
                    'SEARCH_POINTS_MAX': 20,
                    'SEARCH_POINTS_MIN': -1,
                    'SEARCH_RADIUS': 1000,
                    'SEARCH_RANGE': 0,
                    'SHAPES': 'C:/Users/Alex/Desktop/Masterarbeit/GIS/humidity_station.gpkg',
                    'TARGET_DEFINITION': 0,
                    'TARGET_TEMPLATE': None,
                    'TARGET_USER_FITS': 0,
                    'TARGET_USER_SIZE': 0.01,
                    'TARGET_USER_XMIN TARGET_USER_XMAX TARGET_USER_YMIN TARGET_USER_YMAX': None,
                    'TARGET_OUT_GRID': 'C:/Users/Alex/Desktop/Masterarbeit/GIS/idw_raster'
                }
            )
```

This code is followed by raster calculations.

The problem now is, that in the final results I get the values of only the first field. When I check the final raster it is based on the values of the first field also obviously.

Can someone tell me why the raster is not overwritten in every loop?
How do I need to write it?